# Occasional boost::asio tcp server failure run on localhost when using valgrind

Tags: c++, boost-asio, valgrind

I'm testing my application which contains a TCP client. To test that I've created a simple TCP server based on boost examples. The problem is that once each ~5 test invocations with valgrind the test fails to connect to local server. When not using valgrind all the tests pass on each invocation.

I can't find the cause of it. The server implementation:

```
class arcturus_mock
{
private:
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor;
    std::thread t;

public:
    arcturus_mock(short port)
        : acceptor(ios,
              boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port))
        , socket(ios)
    {
        do_accept();
    }

    // A new thread is created to not to block on calling
    // io_service::run function
    void run()
    {
        t = std::thread([&ios = this->ios]() { ios.run(); });
    }

    void stop()
    {
        ios.stop();
        t.join();
    }

private:
    void do_accept()
    {
        acceptor.async_accept(socket, [this](boost::system::error_code ec) {
            if (!ec)
                std::make_shared<arcturus_mock_session>(std::move(socket))
                    ->start();
            do_accept();
        });
    }
};
```

And the corresponding session:

```
class arcturus_mock_session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<arcturus_mock_session>
{
private:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;
    char data[1024];

public:
    arcturus_mock_session(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket &&used_socket)
        : socket(std::move(used_socket))
    {
    }

    void start()
    {
        using boost::asio::async_write;
        async_write( ...
    }
};
```

I run the tests using [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) framework. This is how the test case looks like:

```
TEST_CASE(" ... ")
{
    arcturus_mock mock(1050);
    mock.run();

    SECTION(" ... ")
    {
        client c;
        // That throws sometimes
        REQUIRE_NOTHROW(c.connect_and_handle("localhost", 1050));
    }

    mock.stop();
}
```

Could the problem be caused by the thread which won't manage to create and start the server by the time the client connects to it?

Answer (score 0):

It's a race condition.

When the server thread starts, there is not necessarily any work to be done (`async_accept` may not happen quickly enough). This means `run()` simply exits immediately, and the server doesn't run.

Either make `async_accept` precede the thread launch or use a `io_service::work` to keep the service occupied.